Carbon dioxide on terrestrial planets
I guess it's a basic question, but why do Venus and Mars have so much carbon dioxide in their atmospheres? The vast majority of the universe is hydrogen (and a small percentage is helium). Why did the specific compound CO2 become so dominant in those planets atmospheres rather than other compounds (a different organic compound, or an inorganic compound such as ammonia?), what is special about it, or what created it during the formation of the solar system?

It's very stable.   Once created, it takes a lot of work to convert it into something else.   Most other organic compounds have greater potential energy and are unstable on geologic timescales.
The components are abundant.   Not to the extent of hydrogen, but you're more likely to have enough of it for an atmosphere than xenon.
It's fairly heavy as far as atmospheric gases go.  Any atomic hydrogen on Venus or Mars would be lost to space given the combination of atmospheric temperature and surface gravity.
See also:
How do solar winds affect the atmospheric composition and density of planets?
Gravitational pull needed to keep a gas in atmosphere
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/615311/what-is-this-atmospheric-escape-chart-actually-showing
Besides the above, a planet (especially Venus above) may have geological processes that directly impact the atmosphere.

Why is it abundant? because carbon and oxygen are created during stellar nucleosynthesis?

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14649/why-are-certain-elements-so-common

Basically, yeah.  Anything lighter than iron is generated in large amounts by stars and distributed when they explode, and the lighter the atoms, the more you get.
